# Extracting %CPU usage from VMSTAT in a file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

1. I tried "vmstat > file.txt"
   -->works fine and the output comes into the file.
2. When tried to extract only the column for CPU ie "vmstat 5 | awk '{print $13}' > file.txt" 
   -->didn't work and no output being written.

   How can I extract only the column for CPU usage into a file ?

Answer (score 2):

This command extract only the cpu usage :

```
echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]
```

it will show the usage in %.

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of problems. First the `vmstat` columns can be garbled if you do not use the `-w` switch. Secondly I used cut to get the data, but it was buffering, so I had to include `stdbuf` in the command to disable the buffering

```
vmstat 5 -w | stdbuf -o0 cut -c84- > file.txt
```

Comment: Keep `-c84-` as he only want to save CPU usage so he will only get CPU usage not the system too.

Comment: @Leon Tried your solution with keeping -c84- but no joy. File doesn't receives anything.

Comment: @Skynet  Any suggests ?

Comment: I tried also but I got my CPU usage @Harvey here is my [result](http://prntscr.com/55wnok)

Comment: @Harvey when you run the command without the output redirect, do you see what you expect?

Comment: Without O/P redirect as well, I'm not getting the results @Leon

Comment: A step further back then. Does `vmstat 5 -w` give you what you need? I take it you did remeber the `stdbuf -o0` as well

Comment: vmstat 5 -w gives result and I also tried it however on affixing stdbuf -o0, nothing comes up.

Comment: and `vmstat 5 -w | cut -c84-` ?

Comment: vmstat 5 -w | cut -c84-   not giving any output as well. It jumps to the second line and stands still. As if it's waiting for an input or processing something.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the best result.

> ```
> vmstat 2 2 -w | cut -c94- > /tmp/cpu_info
> ```